# Eliminating square roots in trig identities (Integrating square roots)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate integral:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}} dx$$

I don't even know where to begin, was absent from class the day of this lecture. I know I'm supposed to use some identity related to $$1+\cos2\theta = 2\cos^2\theta$$ but I'm sort of lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about a conjugate?

Comment: I don't know what that is

Comment: hmmm, multiply top and bottom by $1+cos\theta$

Comment: Why would that help?

Comment: Because that creates a $sin^2$ in the squareroot...

Comment: The expression in the integrand should remind you immediately of the half-angle formulas. You should try that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $1 + \cos 2\theta = 2 \cos^2 \theta$, then $$1 - \cos 2\theta = 2 \sin^2 \theta,$$ because by adding these two equations together, you would get $$2 = 2 \cos^2 \theta + 2 \sin^2 \theta,$$ where upon dividing by $2$ you recover the circular identity $$1 = \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta.$$  Consequently, $$\frac{1 - \cos 2\theta}{2} = \sin^2 \theta,$$ and taking square roots gives $$\sin \theta = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos 2\theta}{2}}.$$  Now let $\theta = x/2$.  What do you get?

Comment: How did you get the $1 + cos2\theta = 2cos^2\theta$ and $1-cos2\theta = 2sin^2\theta$ ??

Comment: You supplied the first identity.  I derived the second based on the first, with the help of the circular identity.

Comment: Now, if you want to derive these from scratch, that is a different question altogether.  If you know the addition identity $$\cos(a+b) = \cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b,$$ then letting $a = b = \theta$ immediately yields the double angle identity $$\cos 2\theta = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta.$$  From here, you can use the circular identity $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$ to get $$\cos 2\theta = (1 - \sin^2 \theta) - \sin^2 \theta = 1 - 2 \sin^2 \theta,$$ or $$\cos 2\theta = \cos^2 \theta - (1 - \cos^2 \theta) = 2 \cos^2 \theta - 1.$$

Comment: Still not sure where to go from here... if I substitute $\frac x2$ for $\theta$ I would get $1-cos2(\frac x2) = 2sin^2(\frac x2)$...which would come out to $1-cosx = 2sin^2x$...and then I just plug that into square root?

Comment: Why did you substitute it at the *beginning*?  I went through all that trouble to derive $$\sin \theta = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos 2\theta}{2}},$$ and **then** suggested to substitute $\theta = x/2$.

Comment: Because I I substitute into that equation you just gave, it comes out to $sin \frac x2 = \sqrt(\frac {1-cos(\frac x2)}{2}$ and I don't know what to do with that... I'm not getting why you need to substitute $\frac x2$

Comment: With the substitution $\theta = x/2$, we get $$\cos 2\theta = \cos 2(x/2) = \cos x,$$ **NOT** $\cos x/2$.  Then the RHS becomes $$\sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos x}{2}}$$ which is the integrand in your original question, meaning that $$\int \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}} \, dx = \int \sin \frac{x}{2} \, dx.$$  If you cannot see this, then you have a more serious deficiency in your mathematics proficiency than what can be addressed through this website.

Comment: Ahhaa I forgot about the 2 next to the theta, thank you for being patient with me, I get it now :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** You may use
$$
\sin^2 \frac{x}2=\frac{1-\cos x}2
$$ and $\sin u \geq0, \, u \in [0,\pi].$

Comment: Where did you get that identity from? Or what is it called?

Comment: @bankey If you know that $\cos (a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a \sin b$, then just just apply it to $\cos a=\cos (a/2+a/2)$ and use $\cos^2 (a/2)=1-\sin^2 (a/2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, the formula $$\cos x=1-2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\ dx$$
Hence, $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}}\ dx=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{\frac{1-1+2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}{2}}\ dx$$

$$=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\frac{x}{2} dx$$
$$=2(2)\left[-\cos\frac{x}{2}\right]_{0}^{\pi}=\color{red}{4}$$